# Failing to use gst-launch-1.0

Tags: gstreamer

I have a camera connected to my raspberry pi 4.
When I try

```
libcamera-video -t 5000
```

I can see the video no problem. I still might have to investigate its options to correct certain details but it is working

However when I try to use `gst-launch-1.0` it does not work with `v4l2src`

For background when I do

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw, width=500,height=500",format=GRAY16_LE ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

I got a video (not the camera) but `ximagesink` does not work

I tried several combinations of

```
gst-launch-1.0 -vv4l2src device=/dev/video0 num-buffers=1 ! "video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate=30/1" ! xvimagesink
```

it fails with

```
ERROR: from element /GstPipeLine:pipeline0/Gstv4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info
../libs/gst/basegstbasesrc.c(3132): gst_base_src_loop () /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:  
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
```

How can I  get the camera info with gst-launch-1.0 in the raspberri pi 4?